# Making a Ruby array string into an array of integers

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

I have an array (which is technically a string) of id numbers.

```
ids = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
```

I want to make the ids into an array that looks like this:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The only way I've found to do this is to use map.

```
id_numbers = ids.split(/,\s?/).map(&:to_i)
```

However, this lops off the first number in the array and replaces it with 0.

```
id_numbers = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is there a better way to go about converting a string array into a regular array?

Comment: Not  "technically", it *is* a string, not an array at all. Why not just make an array?

Comment: `eval ids` is one way. Care must be taken when using [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) (for security reasons), but it is an essential Ruby method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Using `eval` is like sitting at the top of a hill in a lightning storm. It's never a good plan and it's hard to do it safely.

Comment: @tadman, I like the analogy, even better if it's a steel chair and the person is wearing a [pickelhaube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickelhaube).

Answer (score 5):

Since this is actually in JSON format the answer is easy:

```
require 'json'

id_json = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"

ids = JSON.load(id_json)
```

The reason your solution "lops off" the first number is because of the way you're splitting. The first "number" in your series is actually `"[1"` which to Ruby is not a number, so it converts to 0 by default.

Comment: Why use JSON when you can do this with core ruby? See @cary-swoveland answer below.

Comment: @lacostenycoder While that solution does pick out the numbery parts it doesn't detect any problems which might be important. It will gleefully parse `"INVALID DOCUMENT DO NOT READ ERROR#19"` as `[19]`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I tried your JSON fix and then I began encountering some other issues farther down in my code. Cary's suggestion wound up being a bit more simple and effective for my needs, so I'll probably go with that.  :)

Comment: @tadman while that may be true, we might not want to make assumptions about the reliability of the input data.  But if that's the reason you've chosen to not use a core Ruby method, add that to your answer.

Comment: @lacostenycoder JSON is bundled with the Ruby standard library, so it's core.

Comment: stdlib not core, but why are we arguing over semantics?  User has already explained why your proposed solution introduces more problems than it solves.   https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Comment: @lacostenycoder It introduces unspecified "problems" which I can't address, otherwise I would. In a general sense when you have JSON data you use a JSON parser unless you have specific reasons that won't work. The Ruby Standard Library is provided as a convenience and there's no reason to not use it just because, by a very narrow definition, it's not "core".

Comment: Just because a string object resembles JSON doesn't mean it is JSON. You obviously can't concede on that point. See rule 1 of deployment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices

Comment: @lacostenycoder If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck... The reason I'm extremely hesitant to use a number-plucking system is because it can go haywire and you'll never know. One of the biggest sins in programming is "defensive programming" where your method quietly blunders along even in the face of garbage data instead of erroring out and alerting people to the problem.

Comment: @lacostenycoder *"Just because a string object resembles JSON doesn't mean it is JSON"* in this case that is exactly what it means.  If a JSON compliant parser can parse it then I guess *"it is JSON"*. Although `JSON` is not a thing that something is or is not it is merely a text representation of what something could be parsed into, in this case an `Array`. What is or is not JSON compliant is based solely on [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) and the provided string is definitely JSON compliant.

Comment: all fair points.  It would be interesting to know why the user experienced errors as a result of using JSON.  In any case, it's probably useful to understand why both ways work and what the pros/cons of each are. Good thread and thanks for explaining your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to use `JSON`,

```
ids.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If `ids` may contain the string representation of negative integers, change the regex to `/-?\d+/`.

Comment: This wound up being exactly what I needed... thank you!

Comment: If this answer was what you went with, please remember to click the checkmark icon next to the top of the answer, to confirm this is the winning answer, and move it to the top (and credit the author's reputation rating;)

Comment: I appreciate the greenie, but I always advise those newish to SO to wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection. Quick selections may discourage other answers and, imo, are discourteous to those still preparing answers. Free free to remove your selection and to later select another answer if you find it more helpful than mine. This is not inconsistent with @Phlip`'s advice, as I have only the addressed the question of when an asker should consider making a selection.

Comment: @CarySwoveland take a look at my answer. You need to adjust yours a bit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Thanks, green check has been removed for now.  Still new to this, so I'm not super familiar with SO etiquette :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh, my... Must be really tired. Perfect answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize: you get `0` as first element in the array because of non-digital character at the beginning of your string:

```
p '[1'.to_i         #=> 0
```

Maybe there is a better way to recieve original string. If there is no other way to recieve that string you can simply get rid off first character and your own solution will work:

```
ids = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11]"

p ids[1..-1].split(",").map(&:to_i)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11]
```

[@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman)'s and [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland)'s solutions work perfectly fine. Alternatively:

```
ids = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11]"

p ids.tr("^-0-9", ' ').split.map(&:to_i)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11]
```

Keep in mind that `&:` first appeared in Ruby 1.8.7.